# Past tense or Present Perfect tense

Tags: past-vs-present-perfect

Which tense would be appropriate for the below example,

> 20,000 dollars **received** as donation from January 2017 to till date
>
> 20,000 dollars **has been received** as donation from January 2017 to till date

The donation was received already and I'm going to report it to someone in a presentation. So I'm confused about whether I have to use simple past tense, because the donation was received and completed (or) I have to use present perfect tense because the donation was received however it is still related to the current moment because I've mentioned "to till date".

I'm confused because I have mentioned a time period from past to till date.

So please help me.

A simple explanation or answer is enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Received" is a transitive verb, so you need a subject and an object.  You have no subject for the first sentence, so it's ungrammatical unless you make it passive:

> $20K in donations **were received** from January 2017 until now.

The present perfect is also fine if and only if the date range is from some time until the current date:

> $20K in donations **have been received** since January 2017.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can i use "until now" in your present perfect example (second one)?

Comment: @Raj33  That's actually a more complicated question than you might think.  "Until now" implies a *change* of some kind and so doesn't fit every context.  *"Until now, this factory **has been producing** shoes, but going forward we will also be producing hats."*  It doesn't make sense to use here unless there is a change in the amount of donations, and even then, it depends on what kind of change.